# How can I send RS-232 serial data to a Tandy plotter reliably?

Tags: serial, rs232, radio-shack, plotter

I recently rescued my Tandy CGP-115 plotter from the attic and had the idea to try and drive it from a modern machine.

I have a FTDI CHIPI-X10 RS-232 adapter and installed drivers on a MacBook.

I have assembled a lead (DE-9 female to 4-pin DIN), according to what I've been able to read up about the Tandy Color Computer serial port, as per the following:

- TXD - pin 3 -> DIN pin 4
- GND - pin 5 -> DIN pin 3
- CTS - pin 8 -> DIN pin 2

I believe I have the correct Python code to send data to the plotter:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.usbserial-FT2XIBOF', bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS, baudrate=600, rtscts=True, dsrdtr=True, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO)
ser.write(b"Hello, world! This is a message from a MacBook in 2020.\n")
#ser.write(b"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")
ser.flush()
time.sleep(5)
ser.close()
```

Something seems to be not right - when I send the following:

`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` I get the following: `AJKLMNOPIJKLMNOP`. Occasionally this comes out right.

Likewise `Hello, world! This is a message from a MacBook in 2020.` prints as something like:

```
Hello, world! This is a messaa i 
                                 2020.

2020.

2020.
```

So something's up, obviously, arguably something to do with the handshaking. Have I wired the cable correctly? I have tried the parallel port and that appears to work fine. (And why the echoing of the last few chars? Could that be electrical rather than logical?)

I have also tried wiring other pins to DIN pin 2 in case I've misunderstood the handshaking: DSR, DTR, DSR/CTS together, even RXD, with similar results. Sometimes the printing is delayed for a second or two, suggesting the sender timed out the handshake and just flushed the data anyways. I've also tried various combinations in the code, `serial.EIGHTBITS`, `rtscts=False`, `dsrdtr=False`, without success.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Is it configured to use hardware flow control or XON/XOFF?

Comment: To figure out if this is a handshaking problem, try sending a character at a time with a second of sleep between characters.

Comment: @mannaggia as I understand it this is hardware flow control. It was designed to be used with the Tandy CoCo and according to https://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue37/coco_printer.php generic printers should connect pin 2 to DTR.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Yes sorry I forgot to add that, I did do exactly that and it printed the characters ok. (Actually with 0.25 seconds of sleep between characters.)

Comment: You need one of these [RS-232 breakout box](https://amzn.to/32vj8xf) except 9-pin (or + a pair of 9-25 adapters)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact one thing I actually do have is a pair of DE-9 breakouts, male and female, and I can patch between them and add LEDs etc. That's almost as good.

Comment: Perfect. The goal is to figure out, despite what the documentation says (because documentation is often wrong), which pin on each circuit is actually providing/responding to handshaking. Once you have that determined, you can see if there is still a problem. In some systems you could add nulls as padding to deal with slow handshaking, but in many systems that will result in a mess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The manual says nothing more than it can print 12 characters per second and it uses BUSY pin.

Even if you have connected BUSY output to CTS input, and turned RTS/CTS handshaking on, there is still a possibility that one or two extra bytes are sent out on the data pin, because the serial string write happens as a single large block, and also the USB packets contain multiple bytes to send in one packet, so it is up to the drivers and the chip how fast it can react to the BUSY/CTS signal.

To be sure, write only single byte at a time, flush buffers after each byte written, and preferably add a delay of at least 84 milliseconds after flushing the single byte. Then, after that is up to the serial chip driver and USB controller driver and the chip itself how will it behave.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the answer. I added the delay and also a loop to poll ```ser.cts```, partly because the plotter's graphics mode would take longer than 84 ms to draw a line. The working assumption here is that the plotter is slow to raise CTS and the chip isn't expecting that. This seemed to work and I observed CTS going up and down; I can now experiment with the delay length and see how short it can be before problems arise. If my question is of general interest it might be around "are there timing issues in vintage serial devices" or "do they degrade as they age and why"

Comment: And the answers to that general questions would be "Of course", and "YMMV" - As it is, with a specific example, it is much better ;)

Comment: The buffering behavior of PC UART chips is IMHO horrible.  When a receiving device deasserts CTS, that should cause a transmitting device to refrain from starting any new characters.  Unfortunately, on many PC UART chips, there's no way to enable receive buffering without also causing the devices to transmit up to 64 bytes after the far end has deasserted CTS, which will virtually guarantee data loss if the far-end device doesn't have 64 bytes of buffer remaining when it deasserts CTS.  Since many devices...

Comment: ...have less than 64 bytes of buffering *in total*, it is grossly unreasonable to expect them to deassert CTS while 64 bytes or more of buffering remain.

Comment: @supercat The 16550 UART only has a 16-byte FIFO..

Comment: @RossRidge It does. But a PC might not have a 16550 any more. If they are not integrated, PCIe addon cards have UARTs with larger FIFOs, like 16950 has 128 bytes. The original poster uses a USB connected UART which brings quirks of its own, and it has 512 byte FIFOs.

Comment: Thank you @supercat - I pretty much expected to have to nurse it into working but yes, as you say, implementations are banking on receiving buffers that vintage devices could sometimes ill-afford. Commercially now not a priority of course. Seems a shame there is no "stricter" mode UARTs could be put into somehow. I seem to remember reading somewhere that this plotter has an 8-byte buffer, but I might have imagined that.

Comment: @Justme  They could, but the standard PC UART chip that supercat was talking about is still a 16550 compatible UART with a 16-bit FIFO.

Comment: The 16550 transmit FIFO has no hardware flow control, so it is up to the driver how much it writes to TX FIFO at once to flow out, and this is usually configurable. If driver is set to write 16 bytes into TX FIFO at once, 16 bytes flow out and it can't be stopped. At least in Windows, driver properties page can be used to set the TX FIFO depth to 1. Almost same as just unticking the "Use FIFO" box. Fortunately, writing a single byte and flushing the buffer will usually do the trick too.

Comment: @Justme: Many USB UARTs are better with regard to handshaking.  If configured for RTS/CTS handshaking and connected to a device that will releases CTS upon receipt of a start bit (or at any time prior to the end of the stop bit) and doesn't reassert it until they're ready for the next byte, they will feed out one character at a time.  Unfortunately, many such UARTs have other problems, such as dropping any characters that are received immediately before a long break.

Comment: @Justme: Unfortunately, from what I can tell, the 16550-style UARTs don't provide options to disable the transmit buffer without also disabling the receive buffer, and when the buffers are enabled they don't include any means of interrupting the CPU when the buffer has run dry.  Adding buffers without support for automatic RTS/CTS simply strikes me as silly design; about the only thing that's worse is the way some 8051 clones handle buffering.  On an 8051, if a character arrives, it will set an interrupt flag.  If the interrupt isn't processed before another arrives...

Comment: ...the latter byte will get dropped.  The programmer is responsible for clearing the interrupt flag.  On some fancier devices, if a second character arrives, it will get buffered but if the receive-character flag was set at the time and a programmer clears it after reading the first character, code will have no way of knowing about the character in the buffer.  The next time a character arrives, the RI flag will get set, but when code goes to read a byte it will retrieve the *previous* byte, rather than the one that just arrived.

Comment: @supercat Yes both FIFOs are either disabled or enabled, but the driver can itself decide how much of TX FIFO, if any, it wants to use. From TX FIFO, all that is known if it is empty, or not. When empty, driver can simply send 1 byte at a time, or up to 16 at a time. And RX treshold has 4 configurable levels when to trigger. Yes, RTS/CTS does not apply to FIFO. Indeed USB chips and their serial engines or firmware can be made to react to CTS better. For example the USB chipset I typically use, the manufacturer datasheet guarantees that when CTS rises, from 0 to up to 3 bytes are transmitted.

Comment: @Justme: Hmmm... looking at the 16550 data sheet, I guess the chip reports when the transmit FIFO is empty, rather than when it's full, so I guess sending out one byte per interrupt would work, though the design lacks any way for a programmer to know how much data may be sent to the FIFO at any given time.  Less broken then I'd thought, perhaps, but still a poor design.

Comment: @supercat Yes, it is not possible to keep FIFO filled at all times or know how much it contains. Only when it is says it's empty, it is known that 0 to 16 bytes can be written to it for transmission, and it will again interrupt when empty. So even with FIFOs accidentally turned on, an application supporting only 8250 is still (mostly) compatible with it. FIFO is simply used to reduce interrupt overhead from 1interrupt per byte to 1 interrupt per 16 bytes.

Comment: Just a small update to this after a few years experience on related projects. I wrote a utility to take flow control out of the hands of the device, monitor CTS (or XOFF/XON status for that matter), and introduce a delay to send data no faster than the baud rate. Generalising from that script. This has given good results so far. I guess it's crystallising your advice not to trust the chip.